# Edit inline row data change with image and dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am working on a table inline edit/delete functionality where i am updating the data via ajax jquery and the code i have work only with well without dropdown/image update/checkbox, and i want to add input[text] / dropdown / checkbox and image update, Here is the piece of code.

How to make this code work for all the field.

ajax working fine with this input field

```
            <td>
                <span class="editSpan contact_no"><?php echo $value->contact_no ?><span>

                <input class="editInput contact_no form-control input-sm" type="text" name="contact-no" value="<?php echo $value->contact_no ?>" style="display: none;">
                </td>
```

below is the Ajax code that is dealing with html

```
                trObj.find(".editSpan.contact_no").text(response.data.contact_no);
                trObj.find(".editSpan.hobby").text(response.data.hobby);
                trObj.find(".editSpan.category").text(response.data.category);
                trObj.find(".editSpan.image-file").text(response.data.image-file);

                trObj.find(".editInput.name").text(response.data.name);
                trObj.find(".editInput.hobby").text(response.data.hobby);
                trObj.find(".editInput.category").text(response.data.category);
                trObj.find(".editInput.image-file").text(response.data.image-file);
```

My question is How to change `.text(response.data.contact_no)` to make it work with dropdown / image and checkbox. so i can add this three below column

```
                <span class="editSpan hobby"><?php echo $value->hobby ?></span>

                <div class="editInput"  style="display: none;">
                    <input class="editInput" type="checkbox" name="hobby" value="Programming">Programming |
                    <input class="editInput" type="checkbox" name="hobby" value="Games">Games<br>
                    <input class="editInput" type="checkbox" name="hobby" value="Reading"> Reading 
                    <input class="editInput" type="checkbox" name="hobby" value="Photography"> Photography
                </div>


            </td>


            <td>
                <span class="editSpan category"><?php echo $value->category_id ?></span>

                <select class="editInput" name="category" style="display:none;">4
                    <option value="Developer">Developer</option>
                    <option value="Designer">Designer</option>
                    <option value="HR">HR</option>
                    <option value="Management">Management</option>
                </select>

            </td>

            <td>
                <span class="editSpan image-file"><img src= <?php echo base_url()."assets/upload/".$value->image ?> width='70px'></span>

                <input class="editInput image-file input-sm" type="file" name="first_name" style="display: none;">    
            </td>
```